# Cannot find compilation library location for package when Publishing - .Net Core 2.0 - Visual Studio 2017 15.8.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a .Net Core 2.0 project, which references a project that in turn has an assembly reference. All was working fine until I upgraded Visual Studio 2017 to version 15.8.5.

After the upgrade, when I tried to run the project in VS, I got the error "Cannot find compilation library location for package". This was surprising, since I was not getting it previously, but I had seen this issue before, and had resolved it by a hack needed for assembly references with .Net Core 2.0, specifically, replacing the default MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider (for details, see https://github.com/dotnet/core-setup/issues/2981). Once I did this, the project built and ran fine in Visual Studio.

However, when I tried to *Publish* the project, I got the same error again. Currently, I am unable to publish.

Does anybody know what I can do about this? (The project needs a compiled MVC view, so I can't disable the compilation using false.)

I am getting desperate, and am considering rolling back to a prior version of Visual Studio (if that is even possible!). It is so frustrating that Microsoft urges you to update VS, then the update breaks what used to work!

Here is the stacktrace:

> Cannot find compilation library location for package 'ShiftSchedulerSPA.Reference'
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths(ICompilationAssemblyResolver resolver, List`1 assemblies)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel.CompilationLibrary.ResolveReferencePaths()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.<>c.<GetReferencePaths>b__8_0(CompilationLibrary library)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, MetadataReferenceFeature feature)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.GetCompilationReferences()
>      at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.DefaultRazorReferenceManager.get_CompilationReferences()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal.LazyMetadataReferenceFeature.get_References()
>      at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.CompilationTagHelperFeature.GetDescriptors()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorTagHelperBinderPhase.ExecuteCore(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorEnginePhaseBase.Execute(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.DefaultRazorEngine.Process(RazorCodeDocument document)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(RazorCodeDocument codeDocument)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(RazorProjectItem projectItem)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Language.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode(String path)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Internal.PrecompileRunCommand.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0(Int32 i)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass19_0`1.b__1(RangeWorker& currentWorker, Int32 timeout, Boolean& replicationDelegateYieldedBeforeCompletion)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was actually found in the referenced github article above. I don't know why it broke after the VS 2017 upgrade, but the fix for the publish problem was to edit the .csproj file to change the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.All** from version 2.0.0 to **2.0.3**:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="2.16.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```